# Intellij convert tabs to spaces during copy only

Tags: tabs, intellij-idea, ide, formatting, indentation

How do I convert tabs to spaces during a copy operation only in Intellij?

I use tabs in my code, displayed as 4-spaces wide in my usual workspace. However, sometimes I need to paste my code into web pages or forums. That works find if the web page has 4-space tabs, but some forums use 8-space tabs leading to excessive indentation.

I would like to copy the code in the Intellij editor and have it convert the tabs according to my display preferences into spaces ONLY in the clipboard copy of the text, not the code in the editor itself. That way I can paste space-indented code into web forums. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be by using macros.

The macro below, converts 'Indents to Spaces' in the selected code according to your display setting in IntelliJ , Copies it to the clipboard and then undoes the conversion reverting the change in IntelliJ.

#### Create the Macro manually

1. Select a snippet of code, then
2. `Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording`
3. `Edit -> Convert Indents -> To Spaces`
4. <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>
5. <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>
6. Edit -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording
7. Enter a name for the macro, say: Copy spaced code

OR

#### Import this macro

If you have not created a macro before, just dump the following to .IntelliJIdea12\config\options\macros.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <component name="ActionMacroManager">
    <macro name="Copy spaced code">
      <shortuct text="alt E" />
      <action id="ConvertIndentsToSpaces" />
      <action id="EditorCopy" />
      <action id="$Undo" />
    </macro>
  </component>
</application>
```

#### Using the macro

Select the bit of code you want to paste to a Forum post and then:

either `Edit -> Macros -> 'Copy spaced code' OR 'Playback Last Macro'`

or it might be simpler to assign a keyboard shortcut to it like so (notice that you can search for 'Copy spaced code' in Settings straight away instead of first going to Keymap and then searching for it there):

[image]